# XSL-FO: How to set dynamic table width?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have this problem:
I need a FO-table, which is just as wide as the width of the content (cells).
But when I add a table in my FO-markup, it is always acting like a Block-Level-Element and using the width of the wohle row.

Confusing for me: If I wrap it into an Inline-Element (which has the expected behavior), the Table has not the behavior of the Inline-Element but turns again to be a Block-Element.

Does someone has an idea of how to solve that?

Here my markup:

```
<inline width="auto">
    <table table-layout="fixed">
        <table-column column-width="6.36mm"/>
        <table-column/>
        <table-column column-width="6.36mm"/>
        <table-column/>
        <table-column column-width="6.36mm"/>
        <table-column/>
        <table-column column-width="6.36mm"/>
        <table-column/>
        <table-body>
            <table-row>
                <table-cell padding-right="1.6mm">
                    <block-container height="3mm" width="4.76mm" overflow="hidden">
                        <block>
                            <external-graphic content-height="3mm" src="image1.jpg"/>
                        </block>
                    </block-container>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell>
                    <block>
                        Image name 1
                    </block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell padding-right="1.6mm">
                    <block-container height="3mm" width="4.76mm" overflow="hidden">
                        <block>
                            <external-graphic content-height="3mm" src="image2.jpg"/>
                        </block>
                    </block-container>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell>
                    <block>
                        Image name 2
                    </block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell padding-right="1.6mm">
                    <block-container height="3mm" width="4.76mm" overflow="hidden">
                        <block>
                            <external-graphic content-height="3mm" src="image3.jpg"/>
                        </block>
                    </block-container>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell>
                    <block>
                        Image name 3
                    </block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell padding-right="1.6mm">
                    <block-container height="3mm" width="4.76mm" overflow="hidden">
                        <block>
                            <external-graphic content-height="3mm" src="image4.jpg"/>
                        </block>
                    </block-container>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell>
                    <block>
                        image name4
                    </block>
                </table-cell>
            </table-row>
        </table-body>
    </table>
</inline>
```

(Maybe important notice: My columns need to be toggling with fixed and auto-width)

Thank you already!!!

Comment: I added the FO-snippet, as the whole document is very big. Is that enough? Processor I am using is FOP 1.1

Comment: My table is as you wrote alternating image (with a fixed width) and text (width depending of the text), and all in one row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is called [**automatic table layout**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/tables.html#width-layout) and is *theoretically* achieved setting `inline-progression-dimension` and `table-layout` to `auto`:

```
<fo:table inline-progression-dimension="auto" table-layout="auto">
   ... columns, table-body ...
</fo:table>
```

However, [FOP does not support auto layout yet](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-object-table); if you don't set a width for the table the whole line width will be used, and will be divided between the columns according to their `column-width` (either fixed or as a percentage), or in equal parts if columns don't have an explicitly set width.

> Confusing for me: If I wrap it into an Inline-Element (which has the
>   expected behavior), the Table has not the behavior of the
>   Inline-Element but turns again to be a Block-Element.

An [`fo:table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_table) always creates **block areas**, and wrapping it inside an `fo:inline` is not going to change that.

**Edit: workaround**

In the specific case of a **single row** of objects (as in the question) **a table might not be needed at all**, and the desired output could be achievable using just inline objects:

```
<inline keep-together.within-line="always">
    <external-graphic height="3mm" width="4.76mm" overflow="hidden" 
        content-height="3mm" src="image1.jpg"/>
    Image name 1
    <external-graphic height="3mm" width="4.76mm" overflow="hidden" 
        content-height="3mm" src="image2.jpg"/>
    Image name 2
    <external-graphic height="3mm" width="4.76mm" overflow="hidden" 
        content-height="3mm" src="image3.jpg"/>
    Image name 3
    <external-graphic height="3mm" width="4.76mm" overflow="hidden" 
        content-height="3mm" src="image4.jpg"/>
    Image name 4
</inline>
```

Comment: You are great, Ifurini :) Very good solution, I did not know that I can clip an image just with 'width' and 'content-widht' and the property '....within-line' was not that familiar for me, too. Fine. Can I give you another 25 points? :D